# Macbook screen switch off when moved

Tags: macbook, motion-detection

When moving my macbook it sometimes switch off unexpectedly (black screen) and switch on again after several seconds.

I remember solving the problem several month ago by changing a internal MacOS X settings with such a command:

```
defaults write com.apple.??????
```

This command disabled the automatic shock detection system that prevent hard drive damage.

Does someone knows this command? a better alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable the *Sudden Motion Sensor* to avoid the harddrive heads parking them due to loud noise in a club.

To check if *Sudden Motion Sensor* is activated, use the following command and look for the sms setting (1 = enabled) :

```
# sudo pmset -g
```

To disable *Sudden Motion Sensor*, use the following command :

```
# sudo pmset -a sms 0
```

To enable *Sudden Motion Sensor*, use the following command :

```
# sudo pmset -a sms 1
```

From http://rc.vc/files/traktor/optimizing_macbook_for_traktor.txt

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you for that but I have one question: what is the first line for : *sudo pmset -g* ?

Comment: I found by myself : this is to check the current value.

Comment: I edit your answer for further reading.